# Firefox not firing inline events on dynamically created elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

**Solved:**

Firefox does not have a property srcElement on the event object. I am using $(event.target) instead and everything is working consistently across browsers.

---

In short, this block of code works in every major browser except for Firefox

```
$('<div onclick="someFunction()"></div>').appendTo('body');
```

I understand that in this example the event can just as easily be bound using jQuery's .on() or .click(), but in more complex examples in which I am creating 3 or 4 nested elements simultaneously, this is burdensome to say the least.

Does anyone know why this is the case and how I might go about fixing it without explicitly binding events in the script?

Full code:

```
oc.twitch.twitchWrapper = function(streamName, streamDisplayName) {
    return $('<div class="twitch-inline-wrapper">\
        <div class="twitch-above-controls uk-clearfix" ondblclick="oc.twitch.doubleClickResize(event)">\
            <div class="uk-float-left stream-name">' + ( streamDisplayName || streamName ) + '</div>\
            <a onclick="oc.twitch.closeStream(event)" class="uk-float-right x"></a>\
            <a class="timer" onmouseover="oc.twitch.setTimerTooltip(event)">0:00</a>\
        </div>\
        <div class="twitch-inline-container"></div>\
    </div>');
}
```

Comment: And how do you debug it? What isn't working???

Comment: `$('<div>click</div>').bind('click', someFunction).appendTo('body');` don't seems so burdensome to me. :)

Comment: @Tyr I've updated the post with the markup that would be tough to bind to  explicitly..

Comment: i've tested the onclick attribute in a div in my local firefox browser with jquery. No problems at all.

Comment: @Tyr Dito, that should always work and the error is another one.

Comment: Thanks. Apparently firefox doesn't have an srcElement property on the event object. I was doing $('<div onclick="myFunction(event)"></div>'); then working on the basis of the $(event).srcElement.